# Word that describes a word which isn't normally used in an everyday conversation

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I remember there was a word which describes a **word which isn't normally used in an everyday conversation**. Ironically, that word isn't normally used in an everyday conversation.

It's an **adjective**. In a sentence:

> That word is ??????, you don't see it often.

I can distinctly remember that it is used to specifically describe **words** (and not general events, knowledge etc). A **word** which is rare/exquisite and isn't seen very often.

What is a word that describes that? I remember it was quite the highbrow word.

Comment: @tchrist, as I read it, OP here is asking for an obscure or rare word, not an obsolete one.  That is, she wants an *arcane* word, not a *archaic* word.  But we need some kind of threshold to understand just *how rare* is wanted.

Comment: @tchrist On the other hand, as a researcher and font of knowledge ... :-)

Comment: @DanBron Madara Uchiha is a godlike ninja who is able to split mountains purely with the power of **his** eyes.

Comment: We usually like evidence to back up claims, but if you really can split mountains purely with the power of your eyes, I say we let this one stand. Sir.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am able to summon the blue 600ft avatar with the power of my eyes (See [Susano'o](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Susanoo)): http://i.minus.com/ibkFY2oZoReMvv.gif. Yes, those are mountains in the distance. I am standing comfortably in the jewel on its forehead.

Comment: Well now there's the evidence to back up his claims; this court surely admits animated gifs.

Comment: What has *archaic* to do with a "rare" word? Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Dan, Kris: True, but tchrist's answer to the original includes ***spanonym** (rare word); **lanthonym** or **xechasmonym** (forgotten word); **chamaeonym** (a lost word, one that’s on the ground)*. At least some of those can be used of non-archaisms. And they're *all* specific to ***words*** (none of the current suggestions here meet that specific criterion as requested by OP).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, those are all interesting in their own right, for sure.  Unfortunately, they're also all *nouns*. OP specifically asked for a *adjective*. Also, though the word should be unusual, or rare, it probably shouldn't be *vanishingly rare*, because presumably OP has heard or read it in the course of everyday life (perhaps even more than once) as opposed to seeing it in a glossary of lost words. Anyway, this question is different from the other and should be re-opened in its own right.

Comment: @Dan: How obscure do you want to be? There's always *spanonymic[al], lanthonymic, xechasmonymic, chamaeonymic*.

Comment: It's not my question nor my benchmark to set, but my instinct says it should be a word that people would use outside the context of lists of rare words. Something an educated/well-rounded/well-read people might come across, or even use, a few times a year, say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Dan is right. Sadly, it's none of the words you've listed in your comment, or on the linked answer. This question is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: Just to add to the melee, *lexiphanic.*

Comment: @Madara: When you say ***it's** none of those*, the implication is *you already know the word you're looking for*, and you're just looking to ELU to jog your memory. I do not think that's an appropriate position to take, since it automatically disqualifies all other words even if they might actually be "better" for the context than the one you have in mind.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't mind a better word (and I don't think that visitors from Google would mind either). But I do remember that there was a specific word for it, and it does drive me insane that I can't remember what it was (I've been browsing chat logs for about a month with no success).

Comment: @FumbleFingers : that's *exactly* the difference meant to be drawn out by "accepted" vs "most upvoted". The community decides the *best* answer, but the asker decides the *right* answer. We do not close questions simply because the asker has a specific word in mind (for a recent example: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189546/whats-a-word-that-means-to-intentionally-withholding-information/189555?noredirect=1#comment395877_189555)

Answer (score 9):

It's possible you just want

> **esoteric**
>
> adjective
>
> intended for or likely to be understood by only a small number of
>   people with a specialized knowledge or interest. [Google D]

Comment: This seems plausible; by denotation, it doesn't apply soley to words, but in my experience, that's what it qualifies most often (of course the referent of "my" is a guy who hangs on on EL&U posting esoteric words...)

Comment: I won't criticise, though I'm soley tempted ;-)

Comment: Playing off *esoteric*, perhaps you could add *rarified* to your answer? "distant from the lives and concerns of ordinary people."

Comment: I don't think that 'rarified' collocates too well here.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing *rare*, *obscure*, and *arcane* are not rare, obscure, or arcane enough for you, so how about

> ***recondite***: little known; **abstruse**.

or

> ***recherché***: rare, **exotic**, or obscure.

Which definition has the *precise* example, in the dictionary, of:

> "*a few linguistic terms are perhaps a bit recherché for the average readership"*

---

If you want to say a rare word belongs to a vocabulary used only in technical contexts or by specific subcultures, you could say it is ***jargon***, ***lingo***, or ***argot***.

---

Coming back to the need for a noun, you could always say:

> My, that is a *lyrical **locution***

Comment: No, the word I remember specifically refers to *words*. It's none of the word you listed above. Thanks for your response though! +1 from me :)

Comment: Is the word you're looking for a *noun* meaning *a rare word*, or an *adjective* which means "rare", which can *only be* (or is *typically*) *applied to words*? For example, *hapax* is a *noun* meaning "a word which is only used once in a given text (or corpus)".

Comment: An adjective. "This word is ???, you don't see it often."

Comment: Ok, let me mull on my commute.  In the meanwhile, you might find The Phronistery entertaining (or at least amusing!): http://phrontistery.info

Comment: I was on the same level of "classiness" as *Sesquipedalian*, only instead of the word being long or have many syllables, I remember the dictionary definition was "A word not normally seen/used in an everyday conversation".

Comment: Or *antiquotidian*

Comment: Ah yes, from the Latin *ain't* + *quoted* + *n* one :)

Comment: @DanBron Just because you haven't heard it ... oh, yeah. That's the point. (So rare it's only listed in my private dictionary.)

Comment: I don't know, I find *antiquotidean* fairly *ambiloquous* or even *affictitious* ;)

Answer (score 2):

> **erudite** - showing great knowledge or learning.

This carries no implication of being old-fashioned, which on rereading the question I may have incorrectly assumed.  It certainly has the self-referential property (*erudite* being an erudite word).

> **anachronistic** - belonging or appropriate to a period other than that in which it exists ... conspicuously old fashioned.

To my ear the word itself at least mildly anachronistic  And ponderously, quinto-syllabically highbrow.

Comment: See @tchrist's comment on the question proper: my reading of the question is the OP wants a *rare* word, not an *old* (-fashioned) word, but of course I could be wrong.

Comment: She emphasizes that it's highbrow.  Your selections are in that respect quite delicious.

Comment: She's a dude. And also, read my comment on Dan's answer.

Comment: Damn those gendered pronouns.  And one-language (Spanish) educations that indoctrinate suffix perceptions.

Comment: Ha! That was the source of my error too!

Comment: I'm following Dan Bron's lead of adding all my ideas to one answer.  Is that the right way?  Rather than generating many answers and letting each one fend for its own votes?

Comment: If that's not the right way, I'm probably in a lot of trouble....

Comment: Heehee @DanBron it does seem to be the convention.  And yet I am concerned the way it leans toward StackExchange being more a cult of personality than of knowledge.  Of erudite people rather than of erudite answers.  (Can you tell I really like *erudite*?)

Comment: Whether several ideas should be combined in a single answer is [being discussed on meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5126/70686) with this question as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably looking for "uncommon".

Comment: Except that *uncommon* is not uncommon; this doesn't fit with the OP's recollection.

Answer (score 0):

You may be  referring to : [sophisticated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sophisticated):

The term refers to  something that is not common but exquisite. The adjective is also used with reference to terminology, [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sophisticated%20words%2Csophisticated%20terminology%2Csophisticated%20terms&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csophisticated%20words%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csophisticated%20terminology%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csophisticated%20terms%3B%2Cc0).

> - having or appealing to those having worldly knowledge and refinement and savoir-faire; "sophisticated young socialites"; "a sophisticated audience"; "a sophisticated lifestyle"; "a sophisticated book"

http://www.onlinecollege.org/2012/01/17/50-sophisticated-words-you-should-start-using-instead/

http://quizlet.com/22171044/sophisticated-words-flash-cards/

Answer (score 0):

Any of those from the English Thesaurus?

> [ADJ] (Fewness):  few, scant, scanty, thin, rare, scattered, thinly scattered, spotty, few and far between, exiguous, infrequent, hardly any, scarcely any, reduced
>
> [ADJ] (Infrequency):  infrequent, rare, few, scarce, uncommon, infrequent, unprecedented.
>
> [ADJ] (Rarity):  rare, subtile, thin, fine, tenuous, compressible, flimsy, slight, light, spongy, rarefied, unsubstantial.

Answer (score -1):

**COLLOQUIAL**, the word is "colloquial" everyone. More accurately, "non-colloquial" because colloquial is the antonym of what the author is looking for, but comes from the same thought process as mine.

You can implicitly negate the word via the example: "that word isn't very colloquial".