# Is there a word or a term for when you say you don't know how to do something when you actually do know?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For instance, when someone asks for you to fix their computer or their cell phone and you just say that you don't how to solve that problem, even if you do know.

Comment: I think the basic word is *Lie*

Comment: This [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/189555/186126) may help

Comment: @KaranDesai You have sufficient rep to flag a question as a duplicate. Go to your link and click *share* below the question or answer that's already been posted. Copy the link in the pop-up. Return here and click *flag* below the question. Select *duplicate* as the reason to get another pop-up. Paste your copied link in the "is a duplicate of" text box. Then click "Vote to Close".

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Questions on **choosing an ideal word or phrase** must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: [Dan Bron’s answer](//english.stackexchange.com/q/189546/26083#189555) to the [withholding information question](//english.stackexchange.com/q/189546/26083) contains some words that answer this question (e.g., *dissimulate*, *dissemble*, and *prevaricate*), but the questions are not duplicates.  The other question is about saying “I won’t tell you”, “You can’t handle the truth”, or “You’re too young to learn about that.”  *This* question is about saying “I *can’t* tell you, because I don’t know,” when you really do know (i.e., lying).

Answer (score 2):

If you do that, you are ***feigning/faking*** (ignorance).

M-W:

> **[feign](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feign)**
>
> *intransitive verb*
>   :  pretend, dissemble
>
> *transitive verb*
>   **1 a** :  to give a false appearance of :  induce as a false impression : *feign death*
>   **b** :  to assert as if true :  pretend
>
> I would never feign illness just to get out of a test.
>
> **[fake](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fake)** (*faked, faking*)
>
> *transitive verb*
>   **2** :  counterfeit, simulate, concoct : *faked a heart attack*
>
> *intransitive verb*
>   **1** :  to engage in faking something :  pretend —sometimes used with *it* : *if you don't have the answers, fake it*

Comment: I agree with your answer. 

"feigning ignorance" seems more natural than "faking ignorance" IMHO, in this context.