# Withholding information to protect someone?

Tags: phrases, synonyms

Not like a white lie, but rather in the specific interest of the person who is having information withheld from them?

Comment: Looks like we have 2 questions today in which "shielding" will work.

Comment: Can you provide more of a context for the situation along with how it could be used in a sentence?

Comment: Maybe this can shake someone's memory, because it is currently escaping mine.  There is a term in psychology for this, and it shares the root *pater* as in father.  Maybe it is paternal lie? Or patronizing lie?  Or patronus lie (oh, wait, different SE), or....

Comment: At my limit but possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189546/whats-a-word-that-means-to-intentionally-withhold-information

Comment: @Cascabel Shielding works in general, as is obvious from your example but to exercise our minds, let us be more specific.

Comment: To the OP, it should be noted that ["plausible deniability"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plausible_deniability) does not carry the definition you are asking for. If you choose to use this phrase, please know that it will not carry the definition posted about and will be used incorrectly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the accepted answer would lead new users astray.

Comment: @vickyace Are you sure that the acceptance of an erroneous answer constitutes a close-vote reason?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Unless the OP edits his choice, all this is irrelevant. An answer that doesn't answer the question and a question that doesn't ask what is accepted as an answer. I hope my tautological comment doesn't bother anyone.

Comment: @cobaltduck I think you're thinking of ***paternalism***. It's a little broader than the question seems to be asking, but in a medical context is often used for the once-common (but now very strongly deprecated) practice of not telling a patient a negative prognosis for that person's "peace of mind". This seems like a pretty good example of "withholding information to protect someone". The Bette Davis vehicle *Dark Victory* used this practice and its potential consequences as a central plot point, though I doubt the term comes up in the film at all.

Comment: Cascabel's answer is the obviously correct one here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sounds like *plausible deniability*:

> Plausible deniability is a condition under which a person or persons'
>   culpability might be denied, or at least mitigated, by pointing to a
>   situation that either leads them to take the action they took, or to
>   deny that they were responsible in the first place.

Comment: I don't think this applies even slightly. Plausible deniability would be the ability to deny that you know any information about something, not specifically withholding information that you do know.

Comment: @Hank I'd say it does *slightly* apply, if you look at it from the point of view of the people who don't explicitly tell the person who's going to claim plausible deniability. Like, when the 1960s CIA concealed details of illegal activities from higher-ups they might have said that they were "protecting the president from the truth".

Answer (score 2):

***shield*** someone ***from the truth***

From ODO:

[**shield** somebody/something **from** somebody/something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shield_2)

> The ozone layer shields the earth from the sun's ultraviolet rays.
>
> **You can't shield her from the truth forever**.

Comment: And this addresses the 'to protect the specific person who is having information withheld from them' requirement, which is not necessary in the claimed duplicate.